# ParticleSystem as ShadowCaster

Tags: three.js

Can a three.js particle system somehow cast shadows? I put together a scene and only the cube was able to cast shadows. I've set castShadow to true on the particle system, a pointcloud in this case, as well.

http://potree.org/resources/images/issues/castShadow.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to cast shadows from a simple geometry.

At least in my case, looks like the faces must be oriented towards the element where the shadow must appear (And doublesided didn't fixed it).

So, you should orient you particle somehow in the *wrong* direction . May be rendering them 2 times ?